# Eclipse and Egit - recognising git core.worktree

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, zend-studio

In Egit it is possible using the git "core.worktree" config value to set the data file path to be different from the repository file path.

When creating a new (Zend Studio 12.0.2) Eclipse Project from an Egit repository (configured using core.worktree) using New => Project => PHP Project from Existing Directory; and choosing the Egit repository path as the "Existing Directory", the Project configuration appears to ignore the configured core.worktree value and creates its data path as a child of the git repository path.

Is it possible to create an Eclipse Project such that the Project respects the git.worktree value i.e. aligns its layout with the git layout, and at the same time recognises the project as Eclipse git (Egit) enabled?

Comment: I think support for worktree has not been implemented in eclipse so far.